# JavaScript table filters with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I have a problem with table filter, they work, but when I type in for example John and there is 3 Johns I get some blank space between table's. I think its because I am not using foreach to display my information properly. Also is it possible to make that if you write in theta's name you get information about all the tbody information under it ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 
        <div class="container-bg"></div>


            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <div id="content" class="content-padding">
                    <div class="content">
     <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Meklēt..">

       <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">

        <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">John Johnson</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
  
         <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">

        <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Greg Buchanek</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
  
         <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">

        <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Kavin JP Morgan</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
                 <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Esmeralda Dupond</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
                 <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Andrew JoShnson</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <?php get_sidebar('right'); ?> 
    </div>
```

***My code with PHP foreach loops:***

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="container-bg"></div>

                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    <div id="content" class="content-padding">
                        <div class="content">
                        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Meklēt..">

                                <?php foreach ($division as $obj_1) { ?>
                                <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead class="bg-primary">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="6"><?php echo $obj_1->title ?></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="myTable">
      <?php foreach ($result as $obj) { ?>
                                <?php if( $obj_1->id ==  $obj->division) {?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="p-sm-3"><?php echo $obj->position ?></td>
                                        <td class="p-sm-2"><?php echo $obj->first_name." ".$obj->surname ?></td>
                                        <td class="p-sm-1"><?php echo $obj->phone ?></td>
                                        <td class="p-sm-1"><?php echo $obj->mobile ?></td>
                                        <td class="p-sm-1"><?php echo $obj->email ?></td>
                                        <td class="p-sm-1"><?php echo $obj->location ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
            <?php }?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>  
        </div>
```

[This is how it looks on my website with foreach loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXcqU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it works properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tbody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 
        <div class="container-bg"></div>


            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <div id="content" class="content-padding">
                    <div class="content">
     <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Meklēt..">

       <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">

        <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">John Johnson</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test a</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
  
         <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">

        <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Greg Buchanek</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test a</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
  
         <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">

        <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Kavin JP Morgan</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
                 <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Esmeralda Dupond</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 3</td>
        </tr>
                 <tr>
         <td class="p-sm-3">CEO</td>
         <td class="p-sm-2">Andrew JoShnson</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 1</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test 2</td>
         <td class="p-sm-1">test a</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <?php get_sidebar('right'); ?> 
    </div>
```

***Note :- In above code three different title 1-2-3 give. if you search test a then give output different thead matching value.***

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for replay. But how exactly your code is different from mine ? It's all the same and sorry but this not fix my problems.

Comment: I don't understand what are you want to in your table. Please explain again.

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that I did not explain good what I am trying to do. First of all I wanted to make that when I write for example John in search box it show me table tr with John info and thead, but in my table I have 20 different thead's so it will always show all theads not only the one I need.

Comment: Yeah and this is the problem what I am talking about, you can see that it shows all thead elements not the one what you searched for.